# How to restart or refresh an Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I've got a TypeScript/Angular 2 Observable that works perfectly the first time I call it. However, I'm interested in attaching multiple subscribers to the same observable and somehow refreshing the observable and the attached subscribers. Here's what I've got:

```
query(): Rx.Observable<any> {

return this.server.get('http://localhost/rawData.json').toRx().concatMap(
    result =>
        result.json().posts
    )
    .map((post: any) => {
        var refinedPost = new RefinedPost();
        refinedPost.Message = post.Message.toLowerCase();

        return refinedPost;

    }).toArray();

}
```

Picture that there is a refresh button that when pressed, re-executes this observable and any subscribers that are connected to it get an updated set of data.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know so much about Angular2 and Typescript, but typescript being a superset of javascript, I made the following hypothesis (let me know if I am wrong) which should make the following javascript code work :

- `server.get` returns a promise (or array or Rx.Observable)
- `posts` is an array of `post`

You would need to create an observable from the click event on that button, map that click to your `GET` request and the rest should be more or less as you wrote. I cannot test it, but it should go along those lines:

```
// get the DOM id for the button
var button = document.getElementById('#xxx');

// create the observable of refined posts
var query$ = 
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
        .flapMapLatest(function (ev) {
                     return this.server.get('http://localhost/rawData.json')
                   })
        .map(function (result){return result.json().posts})
        .map(function (posts) {
                return posts.map(function(post){
                                   var refinedPost = new RefinedPost();
                                   refinedPost.Message = post.Message.toLowerCase();
                                   return refinedPost;
                           })
             })
        .share()

// subscribe to the query$. Its output is an array of refinedPost
// All subscriptions will see the same data (hot source)
var subscriber = query$.subscribe(function(refinedPosts){console.log(refinedPosts)})
```

Some explanation :

1. Every click will produce a call to `server.get` which returns an observable-compatible type (array, promise, or observable). That returned observable is flattened to extract `result` from that call
2. Because the user can click many times, and each click generate its flow of data, and we are interested (another hypothesis I make here too) only in the result of the latest click, we use the operator flatMapLatest, which will perform the flatMap only on the observable generated by the latest click
3. We extract the array of post `posts` and make an array of `refinedPost` from it. In the end, every click will produce an array of `refinedPost` which I assume is what you want
4. We share this observable as you mention you will have several subscribers, and you want all subscribers to see the same data.

Let me know if my hypotheses are correct and if this worked for you.

In addition I recommend you to have a look at https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

In addition to being a very good reminder of the concepts, it addresses a *refresh* server call problem very similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good, but it makes an assumption that I'm unsure of: that I am directly capturing the button click. In reality the button click handler is in a different class than the observable work. I wanted to be able to kick-off an update of the observable with just a function call.

FWIW, I was able to do what I wanted with a Subject, but I wondered if there was a way to do it with "straight"

Comment: Yes you can replace `Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')` by your subject. Sometimes you can use `Rx.Observable.create` in lieu of a subject, wrap the listener creation inside it, and return a disposable to remove the listener - but without seeing your code I don't know if it is possible or not. Glad it worked though. There is nothing wrong with using a subject when there is no better option available for instance when you don't/can't have the event source in scope. BTW, some SO guideline : if the answer is good for you, you should accept it.